# Wrong Billing Information in WC_Checkout->get_checkout_fields('billing')?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Anyone know why this could be?

in `woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php` brings in `WC_Checkout` as `$checkout`

```
    $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );
    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
        $formvalue = $checkout->get_value( $key );
        var_dump($key);
        var_dump($formvalue);
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $formvalue );
    }
```

bringing in the wrong billing address

`string(17) "billing_address_1" string(13) "7198 Maple St"`

`city` `state` `postcode` ... only the name is correct for the `Billing Address`, it seems.

The rest of these values are from the `Shipping Address` values.

I know the proper values are in for my `Billing Address` as, on the same page, I performed this at the top:

```
$fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    $billingaddress1 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', true );
    printr($billingaddress1);
}
```

And that does bring back, the correct `billing_address_1` that *should* be my form value from `get_checkout_fields( 'billing' )`

Been struggling with it for a while now, it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I guess this is a caching issue of some sort?  I registered a brand new user with completely seperate billing and shipping addresses and they both returned properly

Answer (score 0):

Update Your `get_checkout_fields` method with parameter `billing_country`
 so it will look like 
`$fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing_country' );` 
**Documentation:** 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#197-281